# Stop jQuery execution after one time execution

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a jQuery script to execute automatic submit trigger on page load
and it executes repeatedly, I want to make a button tigger once the page is loaded

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("[id*='sub']").click();

});
```

**Html code**

```cshtml
@using (Html.BeginForm("GenerateQR", "TRoom", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="HlId" value="@HttpContext.Current.Session["USERID"].ToString()" />
    <input id="sub" type="submit" style="display:none" value="Click Here To Generate QR Code" />
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please ensure you don't have more than 1 button with their IDs containing the word "sub".

Comment: i only have a button with  id=sub  thank you

Comment: Then why not just do `$('#sub').click()` or `$('#sub').trigger('click')`?

Comment: tried its working but still the event is running like a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also i think its better to use session for the same purpose
    
             window.onload = function () {

```
        if (sessionStorage.formSubmitted !== 'true')
        {
            sessionStorage.setItem("formSubmitted", "true");
            document.getElementById('sub').click();
        }
        else
        {
            sessionStorage.removeItem("formSubmitted");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `.one()` attaches a handler that runs at most once per element per event. So instead of `.click()` you can say

```
 `.one('click', function() { ... })`.
```

You can read about this on [jQuery's documentation for `.one()`](https://api.jquery.com/one/).

Since you want to submit the on page load let work around it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
const autSubmit =$(this).find("input[type='submit']);
autSubmit.one('click',function(){
/* Any code you will like to execute    onSubmit*/ });
autSubmit.trigger('click');});
```

After the first execution try clicking on the button you will notice that the code within the click handler won't be executed again which I think is what you want so you can as well disable the button in that click handler.
So where we have

```
` /* Any code you will like to execute onSubmit*/`
```

above you can just replace it with

```
$(this).attr('disabled',true)
```

So that the button is really disabled but the truth is after the first click the click handler on the button won't fire up again.

Comment: hi am a beginner programmer can u explain this with my line of codes i tired like this<script>
        $(document).one('ready', function ()
        {
            $('#sub').trigger('click')
        });
    </script> but still its working as a loop

Comment: Ok let me edit my answer and make it more understandable.

Comment: this is what i need there is a link on masterpage when i click the link it redirect me to a new page on that page the jquery should tigger a input=submit to fire a action  in controller in mvc  the codes that i have tried so far do the same job but when the click event is triggered the page get refreshed to display the output and I think this postback is causing the jQuery to repeatly executing as assuming its a pageload

Comment: The natural behaviour of Submit buttons in a form is trying to reach the server as specified in you `action` in the `form` tag so in the click handler just use the `event` object to stop prevent this behaviour so that you can handle it the way you want. Like this: `function(event){ event.preventDefault(); /* your-code-that-handles-sending-to-the-server*/} an Ajax call will send what you want to send without refreshing the page and the button won't be clickable after once

Comment: script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            const autSubmit =$(this).find("input[type='submit']");
            autSubmit.one('click',function(){
                //$(this).attr('disabled', true)
                event.preventDefault();
            });
            autSubmit.trigger('click');});
    </script> tried both still looping

Comment: Ok the problem. Is that the page refreshs so it the button becomes a new one that can be clicked once each time I can just navigate to another page inside the handler using `location.href = /* one-of-your-routes*/` that way the script can't run and the button won't be clicked again. There is a similar question like this try reading what other people said about this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45780828/auto-click-function-continuously-clicking-on-submit-button

Answer (score 0):

finally got the code working

```
    window.onload = function () {

        if (localStorage.formSubmitted !== 'true')
        {
            localStorage.setItem("formSubmitted", "true");
            document.getElementById('sub').click();
        }
        else
        {
            localStorage.removeItem("formSubmitted");
        }
    }
</script>
```

thank you all for the help